# Compare lists and amend msgbox

Tags: vba, list, comparison, msgbox

Im looking to compare all entries in column B of WB1 (can vary in amount up to 300,000), versus a master listing in WB2,tab "Guide", column A (circa 500 entries).

If there are new entries in column B of WB1, i have a msgbox appear listing the new types to be added to the master listing in WB2.

I would also like a msgbox to appear saying "all types valid" if there are no new types found

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Compare()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet

Dim lr1 As Long
Dim lr2 As Long

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim c As Range

Dim msg As String
msg = "New types: "

Set sh1 = Sheets(1)

Workbooks.Open Filename:="filepath\Types.xls"
Set sh2 = Worksheets("Guide")

lr1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh1.Columns(1))
lr2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh2.Columns(1))

Set rng1 = sh1.Range("B2:B" & lr1)
Set rng2 = sh2.Range("A2:A" & lr2)
   
For Each c In rng1
    If Len(c.Value) > 0 And Application.CountIf(rng2, c.Value) = 0 Then
    msg = msg & vbNewLine & c.Value
    End If
    
Next

Workbooks("Types.xls").Close SaveChanges:=False

MsgBox msg

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare `k As Integer` but Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. Declare all row/column counting variables as `Long` instead.

Actually there is no benefit in using `Integer` instead of `Long` in VBA therefore I recommend **always** to use `Long`. Only some very rare cases really need `Integer`:
[Why Use Integer Instead of Long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520)

---

Also your `CountIf` statement is wrong and missing the criteria:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(S1.Range(S1.Cells(2, 2), S2.Cells(j, 1)), Then
```

Should look like

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(S1.Range(S1.Cells(2, 2), S2.Cells(j, 1)), CRITERIA) Then
```

Where `CRITERIA` needs to be replaced by your count criteria.

Comment: Hi Peh, thanks for your feedback, I've updated my code above, just have one issue outstanding now

Comment: @coyner Just put a `If msg = "New types: " Then msg = "all types valid"` right before your `MsgBox msg`. If the `msg` is still the inital message and nothing was added in the loop then change it to all types are valid.